# adding the second column in a list of lists when the first column is filled with strings

Tags: python

I have been fighting for days to access the second column in my list of lists and sum up the floats.

1. This is my last lab assignment for the semester. Yes, it is homework. Yes, I have exhausted all options.
2. My brain is MUSH at this point.

The first column in my list has 12 rows, all of which represent each month of the year and are filled with the name of the month. The second column is filled with floats, representing the rainfall per month.

When trying to add the second column of floats, I keep getting a `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str"`. Okay, I completely understand this. You cannot add strings because they are letters, not numbers. Here is my code for this function:

```
def total_Rainfall(months):
    total = 0
    for c in range(2):
        for r in range(12):
            total += months[r][c]
    print('The total rainfall for the year is ', total, ' inches.')
```

As you can see, I initialize total to 0 and then use it as an accumulator to add up each float value and then print the total. The list of lists called months (passed in as an argument), has 2 columns (1 for month strings, 1 for rainfall floats - floats are in the second column). I iterate through both columns and arrays to access the floats.

I have tried accessing with `[:,1]`, but this isn't a tuple. I've tried slicing [0:11], but having to access the rows of strings first is creating a break-point for me that I did not desire to enable. I have tried using `total = int(months[r][c])`, to no avail. I am positive that my floats are floats inside the list and not strings, here is evidence: `['April', 2.0]`.

I thought I would get this in no time because I've worked with multi-dimensional lists in C#. What on earth am I missing!?

I am NOT looking for the answer. I am looking for guidance in the right direction. I hope I've provided enough information. I am pretty sure that I'm missing something extremely simple that I'm going to slap myself for in the end. Please help! I'm clearly over-thinking this.

Note: Cannot use pre-existing libraries for this. Kind of defeats the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: To access the second column, use `months[row][1]`. Note that you only need one `for` loop.

Comment: With the requested modifications, this is a good template for asking about homework successfully: clear disclaimer, clear problem statement, clear show of real effort to solve on your own. Good work and welcome to SO.

Comment: OMG Tomothy32, you are my HERO. I knew it was something ridiculous!!! THANK YOU! Now I can finally move onto the other methods and get them done, as well. I would send you home-made chocolate chip cookies if I could! :D :D :D

Comment: Aw, thank you Mad Physicist. I appreciate your kindness! :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you want even more simplicity, you can actually iterate through lists like this: `for row in months` Each row will then be a single list that looks like `['April', 2.0]`. Then you can access the second element with `row[1]`. See my answer below for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are looking for EVERY single element in the list of lists and adding them up. This results in:

```
total = 0
total += 'April'
total += 2.0
total += 'a month name'
total += 1.3 # random float value
```

Clearly, this is invalid. Therefore, you must access only the second column in the array. You can do this with either:

```
Method 1:
for row in months:
    total += row[1]

Method 2:
for row_index in range(len(months)):
     total += months[row_index][1]
```

Both methods are good, but I would prefer Method 1.

Comment: Completely makes sense. I was thinking I needed two loops to access the second column. Looking at how row[1] is accessing the second column is pretty cool. Nice and simple. For each row, we want the second value in the row. I think I was trying to access the column first which was creating a problem. Again, thank you. I will be able to sleep tonight!

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly adding the strings too because `total += months[r][c]` can be `total += months[0][0]` which would be a string.

Instead you can do this:

```
def total_Rainfall(months):
    total = 0
    for row in months:
        total += row[1] # always use the second column
    print('The total rainfall for the year is ', total, ' inches.')
```

So if we try this with the following data:

```
months = [
    ['Jan', 2.3],
    ['Feb', 3.3],
    ['Mar', 3.2]
]
total_Rainfall(months)
```

we get:

```
The total rainfall for the year is  8.8  inches.
```

Comment: Thank you, to you as well. My problem has been fixed and my program will be done tomorrow night after I code average rainfall, and sort the list to find the highest and lowest rainfall amounts. Will be easy now that I’m avoiding the strings! :)